# Exporting a module Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

Suppose I have a module, named mainModule.js, that has the statement.

```
var helper_formatModule = require('/formatModule.js');
```

Inside formatModule.js, I also have a statement,

```
var helper_handleSentences = require('/handleSentences.js');
```

If my original module, mainModule.js, needs functions defined in the handleSentences.js module would it be able to access them? I.e if it imported formatModule, a module that has handleSentences, does it have access to those? Or would I need to import the handleSentences.js module directly?

Comment: `helper_formatModule` generally won't be available in `helper_handleSentences` unless that is what you are exporting. This is due to [how closures work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only requiring a module A somewhere (in module B, for example) doesn't make the functions of A accessible in other modules. Normally, they're not even accessible in module B.

To access functions (or any values) from another module, that other module has to **export** them. The following scenario will not work:

```js
// module-a.js
function firstFunction () {}
function secondFunction () {}
```

```js
// module-b.js
var helper_handleSentences = require('/handleSentences.js'); 
// do something with 'helper_handleSentences'
module.exports = function (a) {
  return helper_handleSentences(a);
}
```

As you can see, `module-a.js` doesn't export anything. Thus, the variable `a` holds the default export value, which is an empty object.

In your situation, you can either

#### 1. require both modules in `mainModule.js`

```js
// handleSentences.js
function doSomethingSecret () {
  // this function can only be accessed in 'handleSentences.js'
}
function handleSentences () {
  // this function can be accessed in any module that requires this module
  doSomethingSecret();
}
module.exports = handleSentences;
```

```js
// formatModule.js
var helper_handleSentences = require('/handleSentences.js'); 
// do something with 'helper_handleSentences'
module.exports = function (a) {
  return helper_handleSentences(a);
};
```

```js
// mainModule.js
var helper_handleSentences = require('/handleSentences.js');
var helper_formatModule = require('/formatModule.js'); 
// do something with 'helper_handleSentences' and 'helper_formatModule'
```

#### 2. merge the exported values of both modules into one object

```js
// handleSentences.js
function doSomethingSecret () {
  // this function can only be accessed in 'handleSentences.js'
}
function handleSentences () {
  // this function can be accessed in any module that requires this module
  doSomethingSecret();
}
module.exports = handleSentences;
```

```js
// formatModule.js
var helper_handleSentences = require('/handleSentences.js'); 
// do something with 'helper_handleSentences'
function formatModule (a) {
  return helper_handleSentences(a);
};
module.exports = {
  handleSentences: helper_handleSentences,
  format: formatModule
};
```

```js
// mainModule.js
var helper_formatModule = require('/formatModule.js');
// use both functions as methods
helper_formatModule.handleSentences();
helper_formatModule.format('...');
```

Comment: Crystal. Thanks a lot!